# ROS2 - Remote Node Setup

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible using ROS2, to have two nodes on different networks each connected to the Internet, communicate with each other (i.e. publish and subscribe messages and topics)?  If so, any information or insights on how to accomplish this type of setup would be greatly appreciated.

I understand how to setup two nodes on the same network so that they communicate using ROS2 but I can't find the settings or perimeters needed for 'remote' nodes to locate and communicate together.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286788/ros2---remote-node-setup/) by [cbquick](https://answers.ros.org/users/34344/cbquick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [coenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39649/coenig/) on 2019-02-19**:
@cbquick Have you been able to accomplish this in the meanwhile? If so, can you share some insights? Would be greatly appreciated!

**Comment by [cbquick](https://answers.ros.org/users/34344/cbquick/) on 2019-02-19**:
Unfortunately no, I don't have a solution at this time.  I wish you the best of luck!

**Comment by [coenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39649/coenig/) on 2019-02-20**:
Thanks anyway! If I find a feasible solution I will write an answer here (but I won't dive too deep as I assume that there will be an official solution at some point...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We don't have any networking guides for ROS 2 yet.

However, ROS 2 uses DDS by default, so you could draw on those resources to get help configuring your network to allow DDS traffic. For both ROS 1 and ROS 2, communication over the internet has two challenges, discovery and peer-to-peer communication.

tl;dr I'd use VPN between the remote computers, and set it up to forward multicast UDP as well.

#### discovery

But, for the case you specifically laid out, it will be difficult. DDS does discovery over UDP multicast and UDP unicast. So doing discovery across the internet is not going to work that way. This is because UDP multicast will not work over the internet as far as I know.

In ROS 1 you could solve this by making the ROS master publicly accessible on the internet, and pointing the nodes on the remote machine to the public IP and port for the machine running the ROS master. However, the nodes still communicate peer-to-peer.

In ROS 2, I don't know of a generic solution, but individual DDS implementations may have tools for relaying discovery information across the internet. Though I don't think that will be very easy to use with ROS 2 because there isn't a portable way to do it that of which I am aware.

#### peer-to-peer communication

After connecting discovery, you still need individual nodes to be able to communicate with each other.

In ROS 1 this is very hard because nodes let the OS pick ports randomly, so you don't know how to NAT or open your firewall to let them talk.

In ROS 2, the ports that are used are deterministic according to an algorithm, for example see:

https://eprosima-fast-rtps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pubsub.html#id4

So you could open the right range of ports for peer-to-peer in ROS 2 if you wanted.

#### summary

So in summary, it's possible to do discovery over the internet with ROS 1, but not realistic to do discovery with ROS 2 over the internet. For peer-to-peer, it's impossible to predict the ports ROS 1 will use, but you can predict and therefore open up ports for ROS 2.

But for both ROS 1 and ROS 2, I wouldn't suggest exposing either publicly to the internet for security reasons.

So in conclusion, I would recommend using VPN for either ROS 1 or ROS 2, for both simplicity and security.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-28**:
re: VPN: you could take a look at [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org). It's a relatively easy to setup peer-to-peer VPN, works on just about any platform and deals with NAT and other weird networking setups transparently.

**Comment by [cbquick](https://answers.ros.org/users/34344/cbquick/) on 2018-03-28**:
Thank you both!
@William
Would it be possible, with the public IP address to the Internet based nodes, to use the fast RTPS 'Advanced Configuration' options for network configuration, listening locators, and sending locators to specify nodes on different networks and get ROS2 communication working?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-28**:
@cbquick, yes, though it depends on whether or not you can do this without changing the code itself (not sure off hand). It might be something the Fast-RTPS community could answer better than me.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-03-28**:
We don't expose those options through our API, but if you know you're using Fast-RTPS you can get the Fast-RTPS objects directly from our API like this: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp_native/src/talker.cpp

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-05-21**:
Does ROS2 still use the ros_master_uri environment variable?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-05-21**:
No, ROS 2 doesn't use any master and therefore also not that environment variable.